# type mismatch in arithmetic operation between vec4 and vec3 OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, shader

I create a shader its run ok on pc but not on my android phone

vertex

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform vec3 u_distort;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * vec4(a_position+u_distort,1.0);
}
```

fragment

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords) * v_color;
    gl_FragColor = color;        
}
```

I have add  precision highp float; to the 2 files

enter code here

for what I find out so far is most probably an  OpenGL ES incompatibility problem I must find a diferent way to write ne variables vec4 and vec3,  vec3 u_distortvariable i'm update the values on the render method.

Comment: On the last line of your vertex shader you add a vec4 (a_position) to a vec3 (u_distort).

Comment: ... and for future reference, also learn to dump the shader compiler error log - it will normally tell your precisely what you've done wrong.